# Finding points which are not local maximum or minimum

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, maxima-minima, extreme-value-theorem

Consider the picture below:

[image: Level curves for a function f(x,y)]

This is the levels curves for a function $f(x,y)$ where:

- Blue line is the partial derivative of $f(x,y)$ with respect to x
- Red line is the partial derivative of $f(x,y)$ with respect to y

I know that the intersection of the partials are crtical points. However I do not  know how to identify other points which might be crtical but not be local max/minimi points.  Like the saddle point, what should I look for?

Comment: Where did you learn that the intersection of partials is a critical point? There is a critical point if and only if the partials are equal to zero (the gradient).

Comment: @BorKari frogot to add that both are equal to zero. So where they intersect both are zero at that point, meaning that we have a critical point. That was my reasoning, but now i'm not as sure

Answer (score 0):

You should check the second order derivative.

[Second derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test)

Comment: I am unfortunately supposed to use this level curve to find points of interest. I am able to indentify points, local max/min, using this picture for level curves. But I don't know what to look for when it comes to saddle points. I also want to add that the levels curves for the partial derivatives are when they are equal to zero.